# Send email to multiple recipients (with recipients from textbox.value)

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to create a taskmangement in Outlook with Custom Forms.

The custom form has a button (sendtask) a field assignto and a hidden textbox that copies the value from assignto to add to variable (myvalue) to include in To.

A user can assign a task with the assignto field. But with this way I can't send an email to multiple recipients.

```
Sub sendtask_click()

    Set objPage = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("Assign Task")
    Set objControl = objPage.Controls("TextBox1")
    Set oMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set objNS = oMsg.Session

    MyValue= objControl.Text

    With oMsg
        .To(MyValue)
        .Subject = "New Task Assign"
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>You have new Task assign by " & _
          objNS.CurrentUser.Name & "        <h1>" & Item.Subject & _
          "</h1><br/>"  & "Description <br/>" & Item.Body & _
          "<br/><br/>" & "Start   Date:" & Item.StartDate & _
          "<br/>" & "Due Date:" & Item.DueDate & "</BODY></HTML>"
        .Send
    End With

End Sub
```

How can I send an email to multiple recipients?

Comment: I found that .To can accept only one recipient. But how can use it to take multiple reipients from Assign to field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try

```
With oMsg
    .To = Join(Array("someone@here.com", MyValue),"; ")
    '... rest of your with block code
End With
```

Comment: It Works. Thank you very much for the answer. I'm new to vba and vbs and i have spent more than 3 days to find the solution.